# laravel 5.4 Send Email error : Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL in CssSelectorConverter.php line 34

Tags: laravel

I run code on local host send email success. But, I run code on Linux host send email error

This image error
[image]

**My controller**

```
public function vendorApprove($vendor_id)
{
    //dd($vendor_id);

    $approve = DB::table('vendor')->where('vid', '=', $vendor_id)->update(['active' => 1]);

    $mail = DB::table('vendor as v')
            ->join('vendor_contact as vc', 'v.vid', '=', 'vc.vid')
            ->where('v.vid', '=', $vendor_id)
            ->first();

    //dd($mail);

    Mail::to($mail->email)->send(new VendorApproveMail($mail));

    return redirect(route('admin.dashboard'))->with('success', 'Vendor Approve success');
}
```

And **Mailable code**

```
public function __construct($mail)
{
    $this->mail = $mail;
}

public function build()
{
    return $this->from(config('mail.username'))
            ->subject('Vendor Approve')
            ->markdown('admin.emails.approve', [
                'url' => url( route('vendor.profile', $this->mail->vid )),
                'name' => $this->mail->vcontName,
                'email' => $this->mail->email,
                'message' => 'The vendor your approved',
            ]);
}
```

If I comment `//Mail::to($mail->email)->send(new VendorApproveMail($mail));` This code, it working 
I think function send email not working

Comment: exists resources/views/vendor/mail/html/themes/default.css ?

Comment: Yes, It is still there original folder. not modify

Comment: laravel version&

Comment: Laravel version 5.4

Comment: i think problem in markdown, try to use view()

Comment: i use  `return (new MailMessage)
                ->subject(config('mail.username') . ", you got a new message!")
                ->greeting(" ")
                ->salutation(" ")
                ->from($this->message->email, $this->message->name)
                ->line($this->message->message)
                ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
                ->line('Thank you for using our application!');` same error

Comment: try to `$mail->setCss('path to css')`

Comment: you mean `public function __construct($mail)
    {
        $this->mail = $mail;
        $mail->setCss('vendor/mail/html/themes/default.css');
    }`

Comment: yeah, if this help add answer)

Comment: it not working
`(1/1) BadMethodCallException
Method setCss does not exist.`

Comment: i think problem in markdown, try somethink like this `return $this->view('emails.orders.shipped')
                    ->with([
                        'orderName' => $this->order->name,
                        'orderPrice' => $this->order->price,
                    ]);`

Comment: I try with default laravel mail . same error`return (new MailMessage)
->from($this->message->email, $this->message->name)
 ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
                ->line('Thank you for using our application!'); `

Comment: i have not idea), try `composer update`

Comment: after i composer update it working.but not use $mail->setCss('')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formatting of the **markdown** must always be left.

This my markdown
[image]

This is the correct format.

[image]